# How do you scroll up/down using your mouse/keyboard in Git Bash?

Tags: bash, git, scroll

I'm running windows 10 and I've just installed Git version 2.29.2.windows.2

I'm trying to learn Git on Udemy and the instructor can clear his screen by typing `clear`.  However, he can also scroll up and down to see the commands he'd previous typed *after* he's cleared them.  I'm unable to do that. I can't scroll with the mouse. Page up/Down don't do anything and nor do the arrow keys. Once I've typed `clear`, all my previous commands seem to disappear and I can't access them.  I've had a look at the Git Bash options and I can't see anything which would fix this.  I've also searched this site for answers but the most recent one I could find was from 2016 and is out of date and doesn't work.

Could anyone explain how I can scroll once I've entered `clear` so that I can see my previous commands?  Thanks.

Comment: Assuming that you haven't turned off your _history_ function, typing the command `history` should show the previous commands. Note that bash doesn't have any idea of your mouse.

Comment: Note that the `bash` command predates the mouse by roughly a decade (bash being from the 1980s, vs the mouse gaining popularity in the 1990s). This has nothing to do with Git, it's basic bash.

Comment: It's up to the terminal to interpret the mouse and it could be configured to translate scroll to up arrow and down arrow.

Answer (score 2):

It's not normal for the mouse scroll to retrieve history entries.  It usually scrolls up the terminal window.  Here are a few things to try.

Make sure you're using the Git Bash terminal using Mintty, **not** the Windows command prompt running bash.

Up-arrow and down-arrow are the same as Ctrl-P and Ctrl-N.

Run `stty sane`.

Do `bind -p |less` and look at the entries for next-history and previous-history.  They should look like:

```
"\C-n": next-history
"\eOB": next-history
"\e[B": next-history
"\C-p": previous-history
"\eOA": previous-history
"\e[A": previous-history
```

Check your ~./inputrc and /etc/inputrc files.

Read the Bash man page sections for READLINE and bind.